# Storing a boolean with Redmine provided plugin settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am developing a plugin for the Redmine project management system. To configure the plugin I am using the framework-provided settings partial. I need to store a boolean value that should be set and unset using a checkbox.

While

```
<input  type="text" id="settings_mytext"
            value="<%= settings['mytext'] %>"
            name="settings[mytext]"
>
```

works for string and numeric values, the following does not work for boolean values or any values at all.

```
<input  type="checkbox" id="settings_myboolean"
            checked="<%= settings['myboolean'] %>"
            value="<%= settings['myboolean'] %>"
            name="settings[myboolean]"
>
```

So does anyone know how to store the checked state of a checkbox using the Redmine provided plugin settings page?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try this way https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_omniauth_google/blob/master/app/views/settings/_google_settings.html.erb#L15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [way](https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_omniauth_google/blob/6b2deedbc5fc81936a1561480f587d469857cffd/app/views/settings/_google_settings.html.erb#L15):

```
<p>
  <label>Oauth authentification:</label>
  <%= check_box_tag "settings[oauth_authentification]", true, @settings[:oauth_authentification] %>
</p>
```